# How to change layout in OS X like shift=English, ctrl=Russian?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keybindings

How to change layout in OS X like <kbd>Shift</kbd>=English, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>=Russian?

Like in Punto Switcher in Windows or Xneur in Linux?

Comment: Why don't you just use [Punto Switcher](https://punto.yandex.ru/download/?os=mac) for Mac OS X?

Comment: Please clarify in your question if you want the automatic layout switch feature or just want to quickly switch different keyboard layouts (which can be done with cmd-space)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the keyboard layout easily first of all go to

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources

and select the layouts you want to use.

Then, at the bottom of the window, you must check the option "Show input menu in menu bar". Now a little flag with the layout-country will appear in the menu bar and you can easily switch layout from that.

See screenshots attached

As instead, if you're more comfortable with keyboard switch, select the layouts as I suggested before in Keyboard Preferences and then do *cmd+space*: a little transparent window will appear at the center of the screen and by pressing (again) *space* you can move all the way up & down, selecting the layout you prefer.

[image: The menu bar icon]
[image: The keyboard preferences]

Comment: This answer doesn't meet the question. Well, the question is difficult to read. xNeur and PuntoSwitcher are apps which automatically switch the keyboard layout depending on language specific character sequences. E.g if you enter Drswga with your english input source it will be automatically rewritten to Дружба (which means Družba = friendship).